# SQL Server query returns rows more than expected

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql server query that returns rows more than I expected:

```
select 
   b.isbn, l.lend_no, s.first_name
from 
   dbo.books b, dbo.lending l, dbo.students s 
where 
   (l.act between '4/16/2013' and '4/16/2013') 
   and (l.stat ='close')`
```

I want to do is get the `isbn`, `lend_no` and `student name` that book returned date is between given dates and lend status is closed , my lending table has only 2 lending that returned on given date but query give me 304 rows

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what the tables look like.

Comment: Thats because you are `CROSS JOIN`ing the three tables `dbo.books b, dbo.lending l, dbo.students s`. `JOIN` them instead. Please post the tables' structures.

Comment: @James and @Mahmoud Gamal 

 lending table
`lend_no|isbn|index_no|lended_date|due_date|no_of_dates|status|actual_returned_date`

Book table
`isbn|book_name|author`

student table
`inde_no|first_name|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not definining any **join conditions** between the tables, so you'll get a cartesian product.

Try something like this instead:

```
SELECT
   b.isbn, l.lend_no, s.first_name
FROM
   dbo.books b
INNER JOIN
   dbo.lending l ON l.Book_id = b.Book_id   -- just guessing here
INNER JOIN
   dbo.students s ON l.student_id = s.student_id   -- just guessing here
WHERE
   l.act BETWEEN '20130416' AND '20130416' 
   AND l.stat = 'close'
```

Define the join conditions as needed - I don't know your tables, you'll have to find out what columns link the two tables respectively.

I also used the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax - don't just list a bunch of tables separated by a comma, that's been kicked out of the SQL standards over 20 years ago (SQL 1992).

Also: I would **always** use the ISO-8601 date format `YYYYMMDD` to be safe - this is the **only** format that works on all versions of SQL Server and with all language, regional and dateformat settings.

Answer (score 3):

Your current query gets the cartesian product from the three tables causing to retrieve unexpected result. You need to define the relationship or how the tables should be join, example

```
select b.isbn, l.lend_no, s.first_name
from    dbo.books b
        INNER JOIN dbo.lending l
            ON c.Colname = l.ColName -- << define condition here
        INNER JOIN dbo.students s 
            ON ......                -- << define condition here
where   l.act between '4/16/2013' and '4/16/2013' and 
        l.stat ='close'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your `FROM` clause isn't doing what you expect it to. By specifying the tables that way you are doing a full join which is giving you a cartesian product. You need to be using the [proper table join syntax.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

This is a great explanation of table joins: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html